# What tools are there for data masking? (MySQL, Linux)

Tags: mysql, linux, testing

I'm looking for (ideally free, open-source) data masking tools.  Do any such exist?

Note: this related question deals with tools for generating test data, but in this question I'm more interested in starting with real data, and masking it for use in test without losing any special relationships that make it interesting for test purposes.  Generated data is fine for some test purposes, but real-world data will bring up issues you never thought of.
[Tool to generate large datasets of test data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/449/tool-to-generate-large-datasets-of-test-data)

Comment: Use MySQL Masking tool - https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/masking.html

Answer (score 9):

I would be very surprised if there was a generic tool for this - how would it "know" what is sensitive data and what wasn't? For example it would need to examine all your data and recognize all possible formats of credit card number, phone number, postcode, email address, and whatever other data is considered sensitive. It would also need to be smart about your schema - e.g. should it rewrite all customer email addresses to "nobody@company.com" - or does any part of your database, applications, other tools assume that a customer's email address (or SSN or whatever) is unique? Or do you have some part of the application that checksums credit card numbers, that would break if you reset them all to 0000 0000 0000 0000? Or does your telephony system assume that a customer's dialing code corresponds to the country in their address?

Basically, configuring any tool to do it will be as much or more work than just writing your own script, using your knowledge of the application. At my site, we simply made it policy that anyone who adds a column with such data in updates the script to anonymize it at the same time, after an initial audit to find all those columns and write version 1.

Comment: I know there are commercial tools, as in a previous workplace there was a (failed) initiative to use one for our Oracle dbs.  (I wasn't involved with that project, so I don't know the reasons for failure.  I suspect that setting a data masking tool up for a legacy db is going to be a very tedious task though, as you suggest).

Comment: Oh I expect someone will *sell* you something that claims to be this, but like I say, configuring it will be more work than writing your own in SQL because you'll have to learn their hokey DSL first!

Answer (score 5):

If your database is tiny, has a simple data model and is well understood by current DBA’s – scripting “might” be the answer. However, the effort (and cost) to manually analyze and mask typical databases can get out of hand pretty quickly as requirements change, functionality is added and developers/DBA’s come and go.

While I’m not aware of any open source data masking products, there are commercial offerings available that are reasonably comprehensive, relatively easy to use and may be surprisingly reasonable cost-wise.  Many of them include out-of-the-box discovery capability to identify and classify sensitive data (SSN, credit cards, phone numbers) as well as functionality to maintain the checksums, email address formatting, data grouping, etc. so that masked data looks and feels real.

But you don’t have to take my (admittedly biased) word for it. Ask the industry analysts such as Gartner or Forrester who have a number of unbiased reports available on masking that may help.

Hopefully these comments will encourage you to consider exploring commercial products as well as internal script development.  At the end of the day, the most important thing is to protect the sensitive data that many of us see day-in and day-out that we really don’t need to see to do our jobs – putting us and the people whose personal data we hold at risk.

Kevin Hillier,
Senior Integration Specialist, 
Camouflage Software Inc.

Comment: I realise you don't want to come across as selling your own product, but it would be useful if you could name a couple of commercial products, or point to some specific advice?

Comment: I understand that you work for this company, and that you likely want to recommend your own product, and am not against that, but because of the sig it looks like a swanky inline advert, rather than "I know what I'm talking about, because it's what I do" ... I am more of the persuasion of "use blah blah blah (Full disclosure: I work on this product) because blah blah blah" and don't put your name at the end. If we want your personal details we can click on your profee and read _that_ sig and click the link there.

Answer (score 5):

Never seen such an item, but having worked with a few sensitive data sets in my time, the main thing that needs to be scrambled is people's identities or personally identifying information.  This *should* only make an appearance in a few places in the database.

Your masking operation should retain the statistical properties and relationships of the data, and probably needs to retain actual reference codes (or at least some sort of controlled translation mechanism) so you can reconcile it to the actual data.

This sort of thing can be achieved by getting a distinct list of the names in the fields and replacing it with something like FirstNameXXXX (where XXXX is a sequence number, one for each distinct value).  Credit card numbers and similar information that could be used for identity theft are quite likely to be a no-no in a development environment, but you only need real ones if you're testing payment processing systems - typically the vendor will give you special codes for dummy accounts.

It's not particularly difficult to write anonymising procedures of this sort, but you will need to agree exactly what needs to be anonymised with the business.  If necessary, go through the database field by field.  Asking yes/no will give you false positives that you don't want.  Ask the business rep to explain why, or the consequences or regulatory implications of not anonymising particular data.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same task few weeks ago. we evaluated some software systems, but most of them are only for exactly one type of data base, e.g. oracle and they are often very complicated to use... so uhm no the nicest thing to evaluate this. It took us weeks.

We decided to buy the data masking suite professional version as it was the most easy to ue one. 
It has also cool possibilities to mask data, e.g. you can change email addresses to real looking ones e.g. ...@siemens.com to mike.miller@seimsen.com.

You can try it free for about 500(?) records as far as I remember.

Here is the link http://www.data-masking-tool.com/

Comment: Just a data point: as of this writing, data masking tool runs just shy of $1,000.

Answer (score 2):

My way of doing this:

1. Make a new database with only view and select rights for the users
2. Make views to tables that should be viewable in other databases
3. Mask columns that need masking by: repeat('*',char_length(`column to be masked`))

Answer (score 2):

I first stated down this path several years ago and have since built up a consultancy based around this practice.

I'm assuming that the purpose is to build up test data for use in test environments where those personel accessing the data do not have rights for viewing the production information.

The first thing to establish is exactly what data elements you need to mask and to do that it is best to start out with a data discovery tool such as Schema Spy (Open source) and you will need the relevant jdbc driver for this task but it is a very useful step in the process.

Talend Open Studio is one of the best tools I have used in recent years to perform some of the ETL functions and you will also be able to do some basic masking practice by replacing values with a random or. Lookup/replace - to maintain consistency - using the map component.

But if your looking for a real data masking tool I have not found a suitable open source tool. If you have a very moderate budget for tools I would suggest Data Masker but you will need to do some import and export through MS SQL or Oracle as it only connects via those protocols.

Check out http://www.datakitchen.com.au/2012-08-14-15-04-20/data-masking/data-masker-toolset  for info about data masking, data masking methodology, data discovery and test data management. There is also a useful blog at http://www.dataobfuscation.com.au

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool available in the Market from Informatica which is called Informatica ILM(TDM). This uses PowerCenter as a backone for ETL and mask data with different masking options available. Altough you need a data analyst or SME who can understand how the data should be masked. Tool itself doesn't provide information which fields should be masked, however there is an internal algorithm or procedure or process to identify senstive data fields such as Name, ID columns with number, Credit card, SSN number, Account Number etc.

Comment: Also, Informatica ILM TDM allows to generate data subsetting. So you can subset the data and mask it or Mask all data then subset it as per business need.

Answer (score 1):

This year I have the opportunity to work with IBM Optim that claims to do what is asked for. Is not free, but it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The one I like best is IRI FieldShield (https://www.iri.com/products/fieldshield) in terms of versatility (most data masking functions), speed (CoSort engine for data movement inside), and ergonomics (simple 4GL jobs supported in its Eclipse GUI with tons of DB and file connections). Price-wise it’s about half IBM and Informatica, though also available in a larger data integration suite for ‘big’ data transformation, migration, and BI too. So it’s not free either, but uses some open source (the IDE, and can use OpenSSL and GPG) and the scripts run on Windows, Linux, and other Unix flavors.