# Estimate large database size and speed

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatypes

First I want to know how to estimate the database size regarding the biggest table it will contains. I've the following :

```
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| users_id | int(32) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| s        | binary(16)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| t        | binary(16)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| x        | binary(16)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

This is the table that will be significant for the size (the other table is only to maintain user data (id, user, pass, email), I don't expect them to have more than 100 entries).

I expect around 7.61263 * 10^9 entries into the table above. I made this simple calculations : 7.61263 * 10^9 + (4 Bytes + 16 Bytes + 16 Bytes + 16 Bytes) ~= 395 GB. But I don't know how to take into account the overhead coming from the dbms (indexes, database structure ...) ?

How to estimate the database size ?

What about the speed and the stability of MySQL running with this large table. Do I have to split the data over two or more databases in order to reduce the size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as your asking about both size *and* speed, yes, Russell's right. You're going to have to actully [fill a table with sample data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/449/tool-to-generate-large-datasets-of-test-data), and test representative queries to see how they perform.

For the size issues, you can't always calculate the exact size for the indexes, but see the MySQL documentation for [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html) and the appropriate documentation for the [storage engine you're using.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html) for information about row overhead and some guidance for estimating indexes.

(for instance, you're going to hit the 2**32 limit on rows in MyISAM, so you'll have to build with [big tables support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_configure_with-big-tables))

As for if you'll need multiple databases -- you shouldn't.  If you need to spread it across multiple tables, you can always use [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html), which I think should also help if you're pushing up against [file system limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/full-table.html).

Answer (score 2):

Write a simple loop that will generate and populate the data into the table.  Then you can answer all of those questions for yourself much more accurately and precisely.  It takes minimal time to do the real world test.

Comment: Ok it works, but I was expecting a better answer ! I don't want to feed the whole database every time I want to benchmark the db.

Comment: Granted, it doesn't just answer the question -- but there's really no other way to know for sure when it comes to things like "will this run well" than to do a little proof of concept evaluation.

Comment: It's certainly true that there's no substitute for a "real" test, but I'm guessing that at this point, "go try it" is effectively the same as "I don't know."  It seems like there should be a way to get in the right ballpark with an answer -- how about asking if anyone's got experience with 10^9 records in a MySql table?

Comment: "go try it" is effectively the same as "I don't know." -- Ah, no. "Go try it" is me telling him to not rely on internet opinions for something like determining if there's a performance issue with a given dataset, database, and server.  No way am I going to write an entire app just trusting that someone has had an experience that worked fine.  Things like server size, data distribution, other databases on the same server, etc. matter.

Answer (score 0):

For MyISAM add 1 byte per row to the computation you gave.  That takes care of the *data*.  For each index, the math goes something like

- calculate the field sizes
- add on 6 for the pointer to the data (assuming the default)
- multiply by, let's say, 1.5, to account for BTree overhead.

For InnoDB, the math is much messier.  The simple answer is to take the data+index size for MyISAM, then multiply by 2 or 3.

Please use SHOW CREATE TABLE, not DESC -- I can't really see your indexes, and I suspect you have a big PK, which adversely impacts any secondary keys.