# Generate sample data for an Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, performance, performance-testing

Good morning,

What free [or trial] software can I use to generate sample data for an Oracle database?

I've been trying with various tools, but none work.

Thanks for all suggestions,

Alec Taylor

Comment: If you could expand on the tools you've tried and examples of where they failed, you're likely to get much more useful answers.

Comment: Why do people think it's different just because the database software changes?  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4814/ ; http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/449/

Answer (score 3):

I like [Benerator](http://databene.org/databene-benerator). It's not super easy to setup but quite flexible.

Comment: Didn't work for me. benefactor.bat 1> log1 2> log2 log1(http://pastebin.com/wk3RKhfj) log2(http://pastebin.com/Em0faE5H)

Answer (score 3):

Oracle includes scripts to create several sample schema and data. Oracle has a [whole book](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14198/scripts.htm#sthref77) (54 pages) discussing the scripts and schema created.  If you want to generate data for your own schema then you should look at things like these:

- [Databene](http://databene.org/) (Mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name +1)
- [generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com/#about)
- [dbmonster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbmonster/)
- [dbmaster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dgmaster/)
- [Spawner Data Generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spawner/)
- [Fresh Trash Generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freshtrash/)
- [Database Populator](http://dbpopulator.sourceforge.net/)
- [DataGenerator](http://dominicgiles.com/datagenerator.html)
- [Database Initiator](http://dbinitiator.sourceforge.net/)